# How to validate and set bearer token as AUTHORIZATION header in spring boot REST API that comes as part of GET request URI?

Tags: spring-boot, rest

Here is my GET Req URI: http://localhost:8080/api/details?token=123

here Get Req comes with a token (jwt) which I have to be validated, it works as long as I'm passing it as a header in GET request as "Authorization Bearer XXXXXXXXXXX" through postman, but when I do as part of URI, it isn't working and getting "Unauthorized".

```
public class GetAllRestController {
  
      Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());
  
  
  
      @ResponseBody
      @GetMapping(value = "/api/test", params = "token")
      GetAllList getAllList(@RequestParam String token) throws InterruptedException {
  
  
          GetAllList result = new GetAllList();

      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
      headers.add("User-Agent", "Spring's RestTemplate" );
      headers.add("Authorization", "bearer "+token );
      HttpEntity<String> entity  = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
  
          System.out.println("this is the token "+token);
              GetAll match = new GetAll("my input");
  
              result.setMatch(match);
          return result;
      }
  
  }
```